# Can I install Ubuntu dual boot on a Windows 10 Dell Inspiron 3505 laptop?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laptop, dell-inspiron, dualboot

I've got a new laptop, Dell Inspiron 3505 with AMD Ryzen 5 3500u with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx 2.10GHz quad-core, 8GB RAM,  256GB SSD, Windows 10 pre-installed.

I want to install the latest Ubuntu distro as a dual boot alongside Windows 10.

I've been looking at the following guide on how to do it:

[How to Install Ubuntu and Windows 8 or 10 as a Dual Boot on your Dell PC](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-uk/000131253/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-windows-8-or-10-as-a-dual-boot-on-your-dell-pc)

however, the Inspiron 3505 isn't listed as certified compatible with Ubuntu, either on the Ubuntu website [Ubuntu certified hardware](https://ubuntu.com/certified/laptops?vendor=Dell&offset=20)

or on the Dell website [Supported Operating Systems​
Your Inspiron 3505 supports these operating systems:](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-uk/drivers/supportedos/inspiron-15-3505-laptop)

Does this mean that the hardware on my laptop will be incompatible with an install of Ubuntu?
Or is there a way around it?

Please forgive my lack of knowledge, I am a relative beginner with Linux distros and don't understand all that much about hardware compatibility with operating systems. I've previously used Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi 4B which I was using as a desktop computer and I liked using a Linux based OS, I found it a lot more smooth than Windows and I learned some command line basics and programming in Python. Also I like the open source ethos of Linux.

However, I'm stuck with this hardware compatibility issue on my laptop. I'd like to install Ubuntu as a dual boot alongside Windows 10 (which I don't like) but I need to know whether it can be done on this model of Dell Inspiron, or whether I should return it and get a more compatible one.

I didn't check the Ubuntu compatibility of the model before I bought it, I'd read somewhere that Dell Inspiron were good laptops for Ubuntu and just assumed that all of the different models would be OK, which was a bit daft of me.

Any advice and help would be gratefully received, thank you. :)

Comment: You would have to try it. Your laptop is set up with UEFI, Secure Boot, TPM2, and a new generation CPU to run Windows 11.  Make a recovery USB before you get set up and try installing Ubuntu. Your main drive is really tiny so consider that as well.

Comment: OK thanks John I'll make a recovery USB and give it a go

Answer (score 0):

For Above issue You can use dual Boot Option . below are the process which help you to resolve the issue.

1. prerequisite: rufus (https://rufus.ie/en/) which is use for making bootable usb iso , Ubuntu ios (https://ubuntu.com/download)
2. Restart the computer and press F12
3. install side by side with window .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).